# Is there a way to perfectly center text?

Tags: android, textview

I wanted to know if it was possible to create a custom TextView that centers text perfectly, no matter what the font is. That's my major issue right now, but I'm also wondering if it's possible to set the specific height using pixels so that the height would also be consistent.
[image: Comparing text fonts]
This picture shows how different fonts are sized and centered. The longest black line in the picture is the middle of the white space. Letters in the picture are the same in every way except for the fonts. The text size is the same (`text.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 450);`), and they're all centered. I hope someone knows the answer to these questions! If you need any code from my app, just ask. Thanks!

EDIT: I am aware of `android:gravity="veritcal_center"`, but that only works to an extent. What you see above is that implemented in the `textview`, but each font has a different center of gravity, so `android:gravity="veritcal_center"` wouldn't really make all of these center perfectly along the screen. I'm looking for a way to create a custom `textView` that somehow measures the height of text and centers it with those parameters. A suggestion by @vmironov in the comments works, but only if the `textview` has one character. I have not been able to mess around with his code, but I will when I get a chance and I'll post here if I find anything. Thanks!

Comment: Can't remember - is it possible to set the anchor point of TextViews manually? Could you create a function that sets the anchor point based on what font is being used in it?

Comment: Could you please share the source code of this screen (including fonts)? I want to try to do it...

Comment: @vmironov [this](http://pastebin.com/sd7rRQLT) is the custom textview I'm using for the text, and [this](http://pastebin.com/H960Ga6f) is the activity which you see on the screenshot. Please don't hesitate to ask for more information you may need

Comment: @vmironov Also, the first font is [Dot Special](http://www.dafont.com/dot-special-kana.font), then [Digital 7](http://www.dafont.com/digital-7.font), [Free Mono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeMono), and the last is regular Roboto

Comment: @TheWizKid95 I have spent about an hour but without any positive results =( Try to play with a `FontMetrics` returned by `TextView.getTextPaint().getFontMetrics()`

Comment: @TheWizKid95 i'm not sure if it will work on all devices and with any fonts... but at least it works on my phone with these four fonts http://shareimage.ro/images/mp1rk5dfbep8fnns40og.png [Here](http://pastebin.com/qtJgyAQj) you can find my code. Note that this is not a production quality code, it is just kind of 'proof of concept'. At least it will not work well with a multiline text

Comment: @vmironov the lines that were drawn in the canvas seem to line up beautifully, but the text is way off from where it's supposed to be. the link to the screenshot seems to be broken, any other way for me to see the screenshot? also, what device are you using?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22489/discussion-between-thewizkid95-and-vmironov)

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to achieve what you want is to use following code:

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="@string/your_text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

set the height and width values of LinearLayout fixed if you want to set the text to be alligned in center within constant height and width

Comment: Doesn't this code work for all textviews?? You need to place each textview in it's own linearlayout tags.. then those linearlayout placed on the screen horizontly with gravity=center_vertical of parent linearlayout..

Answer (score 0):

Set the gravity of the view to "center_vertical". Something like :

```
android:gravity="center_vertical"
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to center your text by applying a gravity attribute to the containing TextView.

In XML you would assign an attribute to your TextView, which would look like this:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
        android:text="@string/some_text" />
```

If you do want to specify a particular size for your text, it is strongly suggested you use SP (Scaled Pixels) as your unit of measurement, and not Pixels.  You could also set an Appearance Attribute for your TextView to control the size,  which is also shown in the code example.

Comment: That's not the `gravity` attribute, that is the `layout_gravity` attribute... They are two separate things that do two different things

Comment: layout_gravity is what I used in my TextView.  I do understand that they are different, but in my case, layout_gravity was the attribute I used for my centering.

Comment: I see, but still its confusing that you refer to the `gravity` attribute when in fact you use the `layout_gravity` one... (I wasn't the one who downvoted you anyways)

Comment: No worries (I don't worry too much about down-votes). It can be confusing to get the different gravity attributes to work. Thanks for the clarification anyway.